# BPY add keyframe to each curve after importing a sequence of .SVG files

Tags: python, keyframes, svg

here my first ever attempt to patch a simple python script for Blender 2.9 that could import a series of of svg files that conform an animation.

I want to be able to enable and disable their visibility so to simulate an animation, this is to be sent to a software called OsciStudio that generates sound from the objects on the viewport.

What I have tried is this:

```
import bpy
import glob
import os  

# path to your folder

importDir = "/Volumes/250GB/16mm/rotoscope/stillsprecol/select/" 
print("Importing all SVG from this directory", importDir)

os.chdir(importDir)

for files in glob.glob("*.svg"):
    print( files, "... imported!" )
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=files)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "Curve" + str(i)


    obj.location = (3.0, 4.0, 10.0)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1)
```

Importing works fine, i get all the files layered and selected, then moved to the specified location and theres one key frame added on the timeline!

But have no idea on how to add a keyframe to each layer, progressively and separated by 10 frames.

I'm using blender 2.9 under OS X

TIA for any, really any, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:

```
for files in glob.glob("*.svg"):
    print( files, "... imported!" )
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=files)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "Curve" + str(i)


    for x in [10,20,30,40,50]: # the indentation in this line is important!!!
        obj.location = (0.0 + x , 0.0, 0.0) # ADAPT HERE
    
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=x)
```

of course you have to adapt the line with "adapt here" to use some mathematics so that you get your progressiveley -> i have no idea what values you want to have there ;)

and of course you can do the "for x in " with a nicer loop...my version is for sure not the most elegant one - but the laziest one ;)

Comment: Chris many thanks your your help. I have understood how the loops work to generate the increment. Now I only miss how to apply this to each layer/curve in the Scene Collection.

Comment: it does it for every object, because in the main for loop (enumerate...) it walks through all curves (which we selected in the first for loop) and in the sub - for loop (which is executed for every object in the enumerate for loop) - that's why every object gets the keyframes. Maybe you didn't indent the for x in [10,20... loop? then it will only executed once.

Comment: Many thanks again for taking the time to teach and share your knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome!